# what is the meaning of "shrink with intimacy"

Tags: meaning

what is the meaning of "shrink with intimacy"?

Borderlands are where the space between two individuals shrinks with intimacy

is it meaning that it cause friendship between people

Comment: It is not an idiom. It just means in this case that the more intimacy individuals have, the more the space between them shrinks.

Comment: Although the meaning is fairly clear here, for the context, click on the top box at this URL: http://tinyurl.com/mwnmre6

Answer (score 2):

Just break it down:

> the space between two individuals

A distance between two people. In this case figuratively.

> shrinks

That distance gets smaller. As per your dictionary.

> with

As per your dictionary.

> intimacy

As per your dictionary.

Answer (score -2):

"shrink with intimacy" means that the couple experiences *increased closeness*.

Commonly, the implied meaning is that the couple indulges in a physical relationship, especially sexual intercourse.

The phrase may be more confusing because you present it out-of-context.

Comment: Why? Can you explain how you go from those words to that meaning? It seems an unfortunate choice if so (shrinking does not help with sexual intercourse, after all).

Comment: Intimacy means closeness, affection ,friendliness. And that is applicable from close relatives to couples like 'the sisters reestablished their old intimacy' and 'intimacy between husband and wife is a key to long relationship'.

Comment: Yes, but *shrink* means to get smaller, and you aren't explaining what gets smaller.

Comment: **Here shrink is used as metaphor.** I hope this answers your doubt. Please do not mark my answer as negative just because you can't understand it.

Comment: I didn't mark your answer as negative. But that is a good idea now that you mention it. You can't say "here shrink is used as a metaphor" and not explain the metaphor. It is indeed being used as a metaphor, but you've omitted the subject of the verb *shrink* which is the key to that metaphor. It's not as if its the intimacy that is shrinking, is it?

Comment: I can't keep on explaining a _simple thing_ and thank you for marking my answer as negative though it was not meant for you. Thanks.

Comment: Everyone should mark bad answers down, to improve the quality of the site. You have not answered the question well, because you have not addressed the subject of the verb in question, which is "the space". Therefore you fail to show what is shrinking, and by extension what the phrase means.

Comment: Jon, I couldn't explain in different way for your question of "the space". I did mentioned closeness. Marking answer down does not change the meaning. I hope stack exchange is looking at this conversation.